# C Caesar Chiper - error with big keys

Tags: c, arrays, ascii, caesar-cipher

I've searched the web quite long for a simple caesar chiper/encryption algorithm in C language.
I found one but is wasn't perfect so I already changed the code.
Still having problems, because a friend said that the programm should be able to handle big key's, too.
For example text "Hello World" with a Key: 50... And if I do that I get the following: (Console output)

```
This tiny application encodes plain text to the Caesar Encryption
Type in some text to decode: Hello World
Type in the key/shifting of the letters:
50
`}ääç oçèä|
```

Which is wrong.... And maybe the problem is the char/array - I don't know...So I would be happy if you could help me with that :)

Here is the source code(with some comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
unsigned char array[100], shifting; //creating 2 arrays for the encryption
//I changed it to unsigned char because otherwise Z with key 6/7 dosen't work
int z; //This is our key
printf("This tiny application encodes plain text to the Caesar Encryption\n");

printf("Type in some text to decode :");
fgets(array, 100, stdin); //because gets() is bad I'am using fgets()
printf("Type in the key/shifting of the letters:\n");
scanf("%d", &z);

for (int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++) 
{
    shifting = array[i]; //overgive values from array to shifting
    if (shifting >= 'a' && shifting <= 'z') { //check the containing lowercase letters
        shifting = shifting + z;

        if (shifting > 'z') {
            shifting = shifting - 'z' + 'a' - 1; // if go outside the ascii alphabeth this will be done
        }

        array[i] = shifting;
    }
    else if (shifting >= 'A' && shifting <= 'Z') { //the same for uppercase letters
        shifting = shifting + z;

        if (shifting > 'Z') {
            shifting = shifting - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
        }

        array[i] = shifting;
    }
}

printf("%s\n", array);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) `'H'` (the first character in the input) is equal to `72`. `72 + 50 = 122`. That is larger than `90` (which is `'Z'`) so you do `122 - 90 + 65 - 1` which is equal to `96` and is indeed the character `'\`'`. Your calculations are not correct. I suggest you experiment with *modulo* (the `%` operator) instead.

Comment: In `if (shifting > 'z')` try replacing if with while, likewise for capital letters.

Comment: I've tried this: 
'shifiting = (shifting+z)%26;'
But It won't work.. only strange ascii-letters....

Comment: Like n.m. said it was the if. I've replaced it with while and now it works... strange... But thank you :)

Comment: Now the real challenge is to undersrand and be able to explain why this works, and how to express this same thing with the modulus operator (obviously the way you have tried doesn't work but there's a better way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is here:

```
    if (shifting > 'z') {
        shifting = shifting - 'z' + 'a' - 1; // if go outside the ascii alphabeth this will be done
    }
```

What's the length of the English alphabet? It's 26.

If you give `z` greater than 26, a single decrement by the alphabet length does not suffice. You should either make sure `z` does not exceed the length of alphabet, of repeat decrementing until the result fits the alphabet range.

Solution 1:

```
    int asciiAlphabetLength = 'z' - 'a' + 1;

    printf("Type in the key/shifting of the letters:\n");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    z %= asciiAlphabetLength;
```

Solution 2:

```
    shifting += z;

    while (shifting > 'z') {
        shifting -= asciiAlphabetLength; // while outside the ascii alphabeth reduce
    }
```

Comment: For me the 2nd options seems better, that's the one I've choosed. 
Thanks for your help.